# C# - NAudio - How to convert a float[] to ISampleProvider?

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm coding my first audio application, and I'm struggling for hours on trying to convert a buffer in float[] format to ISampleProvider. I need this for further gluing together several pieces of audio.
How do I do this? Code:

```
    float dt;//= 1f / nSamplesPerSec;
    int nChannels = 1;
    int duration = 30;
    int nSamplesPerChannel;//= nSamplesPerSec * duration / 1000;
    float[] buffer;

    void CreateBuffer()
    {
        dt = 1f / nSamplesPerSec;
        nSamplesPerChannel = nSamplesPerSec * duration / 1000;
        d = nSamplesPerChannel * dt;
        buffer = new float[nSamplesPerChannel];

        float f = 800;//frequency
        generate(f, 0);
    }

    void generate(float f, float p)
    {
        double koef = 0.22;
        int newSamples = (int)(nSamplesPerChannel * koef);

        for (int i = 0; i < nSamplesPerChannel; i++)
        {
            double AmpRamp = 1.0D;
            buffer[i] = (float)(AmpRamp*Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * (f * dt * i + p)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can first convert float array to byte array. Then create BufferedWaveProvider instance and feed byte array by AddSamples(). Finally, use ToSampleProvider() to get ISampleProvider. Alternatively, you can look at source code of BufferedWaveProvider and write your version that supports float array.

Answer (score 1):

ISampleProvider is an interface so you can't directly create one like you would a class. However we can create our own class which implements the ISampleProvider interface then create an instance of that class to use as the source for a WaveOutEvent or anything else you need.

```
using NAudio.Wave;
using System;
using System.Threading;
```

```
public class CustomSampleProvider : ISampleProvider
{
    private float[] _samples; //A private readonly copy of the samples
    private WaveFormat _waveFormat; //A private copy readonly copy of the WaveFormat
    private long _position; //A long to store how far through the audio clip we currently are

    //We need a publicly accessable WaveFormat as part of the ISampleProvider interface.
    public WaveFormat WaveFormat
    {
        get
        {
            //Return a copy of the waveFormat not the original to prevent others from modifying our format.
            return WaveFormat.CreateCustomFormat(_waveFormat.Encoding, _waveFormat.SampleRate, _waveFormat.Channels, _waveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond, _waveFormat.BlockAlign, _waveFormat.BitsPerSample);
        }
    }

    //A constructor which takes in the samples and a WaveFormat from the user.
    public CustomSampleProvider(float[] samples, WaveFormat waveFormat)
    {
        //Create a copy of the samples. We do this to prevent others from changing our samples.
        _samples = new float[samples.Length];
        Array.Copy(samples, 0, _samples, 0, samples.LongLength);

        //Create a copy of the format for the same reason as above.
        _waveFormat = WaveFormat.CreateCustomFormat(waveFormat.Encoding, waveFormat.SampleRate, waveFormat.Channels, waveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond, waveFormat.BlockAlign, waveFormat.BitsPerSample);
    }

    public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        //If the requested amount of samples would go off the end of our data then clamp the count so its smaller.
        if (_position + count >= _samples.LongLength)
        {
            count = (int)(_samples.LongLength - _position);
        }

        //Copy the requested number of samples from our internal data to the buffer.
        Array.Copy(_samples, _position, buffer, offset, count);

        //Dont forget to move the position furthar along by how many samples were read.
        _position += count;

        //Finally return how many samples were read.
        return count;
    }
}
```

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //Replace this line with your real code for getting the samples and format.
        float[] samples = new float[0];
        WaveFormat waveFormat = new WaveFormat();

        //Create an instance of our CustomSampleProvider class.
        CustomSampleProvider sampleProvider = new CustomSampleProvider(samples, waveFormat);

        //Create a WaveOutEvent for playing our sampleProvider.
        WaveOutEvent waveOutEvent = new WaveOutEvent();

        //Tell the WaveOutEvent to get ready to play our sampleProvider.
        waveOutEvent.Init(sampleProvider);

        waveOutEvent.Play();

        //Wait until the WaveOutEvent is done playing by checking if it's done every 100 miliseconds.
        while (waveOutEvent.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        //Finally exit the program
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```